# Convert bytes array to Hexadecimal String

Tags: c++

Here is a that I write for Print a byte array to hex String , but now I want to save them as std::string and use it later

here is my code

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
void printBytes(const bytes &in)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator from = in.begin();
    std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator to = in.end();
    for (; from != to; ++from) printf("%02X", *from);
}
```

what can I do ?, I want to save it as a string not print(Show) in console window?
any idea!

Comment: "*in C++ there is no function like StringBuilder*" - yes, there is. It's called `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
std::string BytesToStr(const bytes &in)
{
    bytes::const_iterator from = in.cbegin();
    bytes::const_iterator to = in.cend();
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (; from != to; ++from)
       oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(*from);
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<int>()` would be more idiomatic in C++ than the C-style cast `(int)`.

Comment: If you want to append the `0x` to the front, use [`std::showbase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase)

Comment: @phoenix how would you go about converting this string back?

Comment: @anc: you can use `std::hex` and `std::setw()` with `std::istringstream` and `operator>>`